# FragmentStatePagerAdapter does not retain its state when back to parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I'm making a view whose architecture is:

A fragment has view pager that has  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`(adapter 1), `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (adapter 1) returns a `Fragment` when click on `Fragment` it opens another `Fragment` that again has a `ViewPager` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`(adapter 2) attached to it that again returns a `Fragment`.

My problem is when I'm clicking on `Fragment` and returning by pressing back button the `Fragment` is blank, also when I'm using `getChildFragmentManager` on adapter 1, application crashing that no view found for `Fragment`.

**Edit:**
by debugging I found that `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` wont return fragment that was returned previously thats why I'm getting blank page

In a fragment:

```
viewPagerDetail.setAdapter(new ProductDetailViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
tabLayoutDetail.setupWithViewPager(viewPagerDetail);
```

*(if I'm using getChiildFragmentManager here it crashing application)*

Inside ProductDetailViewPagerAdapter:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new ViewPagerImageFragment();
}
```

Inside ViewPagerImageFragment: there is single `imageview` when I click on image view it opens a fragment that has viewpager that has adapter attach on it that also returns a fragment when I press back to fragment that has `ProductDetailViewPagerAdapter` the viewpager is blank

Comment: You need to implement the `onResume` function for the back stacked `Fragment`, so that when the `Fragment` resumes, it gets back the previous state.

Comment: could you answer

Comment: Then I need to check the `Fragment` launching from your parent `Fragment` and where you are using `childFragmentManager` which is causing the crash.

Comment: childFragmentManager at the very first adapter, see edit

Comment: Please share the code segment stated above.

Comment: edited answer with code

Comment: may be i will help for you -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31425717/viewpager-navigating-back-to-parent-fragment-from-child-fragment-closes-the-ap

Comment: How are you replacing fragments? This might be a problem with backstack. Post a code about replacing Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

For the fragment like these kind of nested, we should see for hierarchy of the fragment either we want to see parallel or step ahead or below for step ahead or below choose getFragment manager when replacing and

```
  getParentFragment().getFragmentManager()
```

for parallel fragment replacement

Happy coding!